# How to Iterate the array index in java?

Tags: java, indexing

1. How can I iterate the array index?

for example

```java
int []arr = new int [] {23, 85, 90, 34,15}
int []data = new int [] {45, 35, 65}
int count = 0;
for(arr[0] = 0; arr[0] < data[0]; arr[0]++, data[0]++){
     count++
     System.out.println(count);
}
```

what I want to do is after it checks
`arr[0] < data[0]` it will go to next and check if

`arr[1] < data[1]` and after that it will check

`arr[2] < data[2]` and so on.

until it reaches the last index.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an indexed for loop that makes sure "i" is within the bounds of both arrays:

```
int[] arr = new int[] {23, 85, 90, 34, 15};
int[] data = new int[] {45, 35, 65};
int count = 0;
for(int i=0; i<arr.length && i<data.length; i++) {
  if (arr[i]<data[i]) {
    count++;  
  }
}
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to compare `arrays` within `for-loop` syntax which won't traverse `arrays`.

```
(i.e for(arr[0] = 0; arr[0] < data[0]; arr[0]++, data[0]++)
```

Try this code.

```
int []arr = new int [] {23, 85, 90, 34,15}
int []data = new int [] {45, 35, 65}
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(data.length, arr.length); i++){
     if(arr[i]<data[i]){
         count++;
      }
}

System.out.println(count);
```

Make sure to import `Math` library.

Comment: you will get an IndexOutOfBoundsException using Math::max, as it will return 5, leading to the loop to access data[4] which does not exist, you should use Math::min. also for a very small perfomance gain, move the Math usage to before the loop. Otherwise, each iteration is finding the max.

Comment: @RyanHurling you are right!!! Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @RoopaM and RyanHurling Thank you for your suggestions. <3 I just hope that there is a chat function here. I have a lot more to ask. <3

Answer (score 0):

As i know, you can iterate 2 arrays at once easy if you have 2 arrays same sizes with `for-loop`:

```
int count = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
 if(arr[i] < data[i]){
   count++
 }
 System.out.println(count);
}
```

Or you can define some logic (etc: iterate until last index of shorter array).